# Facebook like button inferred property

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, integration

I am trying to get a facebook like button running. Instead when you click on it it shows some kind of mistake. After using the facebook "Object Debugger", I got this error

> 'Inferred Property: The og:locale property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this to fix: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/internationalization/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an og:locale tag? Such as:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
```

I haven't seen this error personally, but that's what the error message seems to imply.

http://ogp.me/